# How to construct BezierFunction for BezierCurve with npts>4 and SplineDegree -> 3?

Tags: graphics, splines

I would like to use BezierCurve with npts=7 and SplineDegree -> 3 and access its BezierFunction. This code helps:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {5, 2}, {6, -1}, {7, 3}};
f1 = BezierFunction[pts[[1;;4]]]
f2 = BezierFunction[pts[[4;;7]]]
Show[Graphics[{Red, Point[pts], Green, Line[pts]}, Axes -> True], 
ParametricPlot[{f1[t],f2[t]}, {t, 0, 1}],Graphics[{Blue, Dashed, 
BezierCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 3]}]]
```

[image: coincide]

Can it be done better, defining f as a single function, whose plot is BezierCurve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html)   `pts` into blocks of 4 with offset 3,

(2) Use `BezierFunction` on each block and

(3) To get a single function, compose [`Through`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html) with the list of Bezier functions.

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {5, 2}, {6, -1}, {7, 3}};
f0 = Through @* (BezierFunction /@ Partition[pts, 4, 3]);

Show[Graphics[{Red, Point[pts], Green, Line[pts]}, Axes -> True], 
 ParametricPlot[f0[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.7, Red], Thickness[.01]]],
 Graphics[{Blue, Dashed, BezierCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 3]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks.

Comment: Igor, you are welcome. And welcome to mma.se. Please consider upvoting (by clicking [the triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png)) the questions/answers you like and  accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking [the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/).