# Find smallest distance from a point to a Bézier curve

Tags: splines, distance, computational-geometry

I wish to find the smallest distance from a point to a curved defined via a Bézier function. I want to do this automatically. For particular cases it is not to difficult. Here is a minimum working example. What point on the curve is closest to the red point?

```
pts = {{-3, 0}, {-1, 3}, {1, -3}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {2, 2}, {-2, -2}};
pt = {-0.07194, 0.6342};
Graphics[{BezierCurve[pts], Point[pts], Red, Point[pt]}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: figure]

My first attempt was `RegionDistance[]` but this does not have `BezierCurve` as an input. Looking about I found `BezierFunction` which enables me to make a function that gets the distance to the curve as a parameter of distance along the curve. Thus

```
ClearAll[f, f1];
f = BezierFunction[pts];
f1[t_?NumberQ] := EuclideanDistance[ f[t], pt]
Plot[f1[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot of distance from point]

I was now able to look for the minimum using `FindMinimum`. This produced an error without a starting point. However, the point I got was not the minimum.

```
{min, pos} = FindMinimum[f1[t], {t, 0.5}];
minpt = f1[t /. pos];
Plot[f1[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {Orange, PointSize[0.03], Point[{minpt, f1[minpt]}]}]
```

[image: wrong result]

I am aware that finding global minima is not easy so before I try and resolve that issue I wish to return to the original problem and see if anyone can come up with a good method. Thanks

***** Edit*****

Thanks to all who answered. You have taught me much about splines. Clearly `BezierFunction` is not as good as `BSplineFunction`. So I perhaps should use `BSplineCurve` rather than `BezierCurve`. Are there discussions on which is most suitable when? @flinty has made some very good points in his reply.

Due to the difficulty of local minima it seems that using `FindMinimum` is not a suitable approach. The best approaches seems to be that of kglr and Chip Hurst. I have opted for the solution of kglr for now (mainly because I started working on that one first). Here is the module I put together to find the point.

```
nearestPointOnCurve[pts_List, None, sfy_] := {};
nearestPointOnCurve[pts_List, pt_List, sfy_] := 
 Module[{distFun, g, lines, points, p1, p2},
  distFun[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}] := 
   Sqrt[((x2 - x1))^2 + (sfy (y2 - y1))^2];
  g = Graphics[{BezierCurve[pts]}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1];
  lines = MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeGraphics[g], 1];
  points = Flatten[Cases[lines, Line[a_] :>  a, \[Infinity]], 1];
  p1 = First@Nearest[points, pt, DistanceFunction -> distFun];
  p1]
```

You can see I have put in a distance function because sometimes you need the location of the point nearest the cursor rather than the nearest Cartesian point. Here is an example that illustrates this point and is something to play with.

```
 pts = {{0, 0.5178`4.}, {0.0007762`4., 0.4642`4.}, {0.0001964`4., 
    2.535`4.}, {0.000477`4., 2.268`4.}, {0.0007575`4., 
    2.`4.}, {0.0009247`4., 3.202`4.}, {0.001171`4., 
    2.834`4.}, {0.001418`4., 2.466`4.}, {0.001614`4., 
    1.833`4.}, {0.001908`4., 2.586`4.}, {0.002202`4., 
    3.338`4.}, {0.002247`4., 1.774`4.}, {0.002647`4., 
    1.87`4.}, {0.003048`4., 1.966`4.}, {0.002157`4., 
    0.2631`4.}, {0.003`4., -0.1185`4.}};

{x1, x2} = MinMax[pts[[All, 1]]];
{y1, y2} = MinMax[pts[[All, 2]]];
ar = 1/4;
{sfx, sfy} = {1/(x2 - x1), ar/(y2 - y1)};

DynamicModule[{},
 Dynamic[Graphics[{BezierCurve[pts], PointSize[0.01], 
    Point[MousePosition["Graphics"]],
    Red, Point[
     nearestPointOnCurve[pts, MousePosition["Graphics"], sfy/sfx]],
    Orange, 
    Point[nearestPointOnCurve[pts, MousePosition["Graphics"], 1]]
    }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> ar, 
   ImageSize -> 12 72]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Dynamic module showing nearest points]

The black point is the cursor, the orange point is the nearest in Cartesian distance and the red point is the nearest in the screen coordinates.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Not very efficient, but short: `bf = BezierFunction[pts]; minB[t_?NumericQ] := SquaredEuclideanDistance[bf[t], pt]; tm = NArgMin[{minB[t], 0 < t < 1}, t]; Graphics[{BezierCurve[pts], Point[pts], Red, Point[pt], Point[bf[tm]]}, Frame -> True];` There are better ways to do it, but I don't have time to write it up for now.

Comment: ^ this doesn't work because if you do `Graphics[{Line[Table[bf[t], {t, 0, 1, .01}]], Point[pts], Red, 
  Point[pt], Point[bf[tm]]}, Frame -> True]` you get a different curve. Your nearest point is not the nearest to the desired point on the `BezierCurve`

Comment: @flinty, what "different curve", exactly?

Comment: BezierCurve and BezierFunction don't give the same curve. They look different:
`b = BezierFunction[pts];
Graphics[{Red, BezierCurve[pts], Green, 
  Line[Table[b[t], {t, 0, 1, .01}]]}]`

Comment: @flinty, ah yes... can you please try replacing `BezierFunction[]` with `BSplineFunction[]`, please?

Comment: I did, `BSpineFunction[]` has a closer shape but it's still off and the loop is bigger. Have we uncovered a bug? - edit: see here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186949/beziercurve-is-different-from-bezierfunction Apparently you need to use SplineDegree -> (Length@pts - 1)

Comment: Tss... I will investigate later when I get some time.

Comment: Note that if you want to plot the minimum found by `FindMinimum` on your graph of `f[t]`, it should be `Point[{t /. pos, minpt}]`, not `Point[{minpt, f1[minpt]}]`.  Running the code with this fix shows that `FindMinimum` found the shallow local minimum at $ t \approx 0.5$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
g0 = Graphics[{BezierCurve[pts], Point[pts], Red, Point[pt]}, Frame -> True];
lines = MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeGraphics[g0], 1];

npt = RegionNearest[RegionUnion @@ lines][pt]
```

> ```
>  {0.0805512, 0.671604}
> ```

```
Graphics[{Blue,lines, Red, Point[pt], Black, Point@pts, 
  Green, PointSize[Large], Point@npt}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is the way forward for now. However, Chip Hurst has another useful option. I have edited my question to show where I have got to. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Simply using `BezierFunction` is not enough. The `BezierFunction` will not match the `BezierCurve` because that curve is actually a composite of multiple splines - see here: [BezierCurve is different from BezierFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186949/beziercurve-is-different-from-bezierfunction).

This below is adapted from the above and @J. M.'s technical difficulties solution:

You need to first chop your spline into its components and minimize over both, then find which closest point on each sub-spline is closer to your point.
See here on how to produce the parts: [How to construct BezierFunction for BezierCurve with npts>4 and SplineDegree -> 3?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203261/how-to-construct-bezierfunction-for-beziercurve-with-npts4-and-splinedegree)

```
pt = {-0.07194, 0.6342};
pts = {{-3, 0}, {-1, 3}, {1, -3}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {2, 2}, {-2, -2}};
bzsplinefns = BezierFunction /@ Partition[pts, 4, 3];
distance[p1_, p2_] := SquaredEuclideanDistance[p1, p2]
splineDistance[spline_, point_, t_?NumericQ] := 
 distance[spline[t], point]
closest[spline_, point_] := 
 NArgMin[{splineDistance[spline, point, t], 0 < t < 1}, t]
tvals = closest[#, pt] & /@ bzsplinefns;
finalNearestPoint = 
 MinimalBy[MapThread[#1[#2] &, {bzsplinefns, tvals}], 
   distance[#, pt] &][[1]]
Graphics[{Point[pt], Thick, Gray, BezierCurve[pts], Thin,
  {RandomColor[], Line[Table[#[t], {t, 0, 1, 0.01}]]} & /@ 
   bzsplinefns, PointSize[Large], Point[finalNearestPoint]}]
```

[image: bezier splines]

If you choose `BSplineCurve` instead, you don't need to worry about breaking it into multiple `BSplineFunctions` - you can just minimize a single `BSplineFunction` that accounts for the whole curve.

```
pt = {-0.07194, 0.6342};
pts = {{-3, 0}, {-1, 3}, {1, -3}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {2, 2}, {-2, -2}};
distance[p1_, p2_] := SquaredEuclideanDistance[p1, p2]
splineDistance[spline_, point_, t_?NumericQ] := 
 distance[spline[t], point]
closest[spline_, point_] := 
 NArgMin[{splineDistance[spline, point, t], 0 < t < 1}, t]
bsp = BSplineFunction[pts];
result = bsp[closest[bsp, pt]]
Graphics[{BSplineCurve[pts], Point[pt], PointSize[Large], 
  Point[result]}]
```

[image: bspline nearest point]

Comment: Many important points. Thank you. I have edited my question to show where I have got to. Do you have recommendations on which to use `BezierFunction` or` BSplineFunction`?

Comment: `BSplineFunction` and `BSplineCurve` are better together because they are smoother, unlike `BezierCurve` which is really made out of multiple `BezierFunctions` glued together in a sharp C0-continuous piecewise fashion.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline#Relationship_to_piecewise/composite_Bézier
Also if you use just `BSplineCurve` and `BSplineFunction`, you don't need to do any of this stuff with decomposition into multiple segments - it just works.

Comment: By the way, klgr's answer suffers from a tiny discretization error from chopping the spline into lines - though I upvoted it myself because it's close enough and the easiest to understand. If you're looking for the most accurate result use `NArgMin` with the spline function like above.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the procedure with `BSplineCurve` and `BSplineFunction`. You still can't do a `RegionDistance`. Or have I got this wrong?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Also `RegionDistance` is slightly inaccurate `dregdist = RegionDistance[DiscretizeGraphics@BSplineCurve[pts], pt];
daccurate = EuclideanDistance[pt, result]; (*from above*)
error = Abs[dregdist - daccurate]` gives 0.0000455788

Comment: Thanks. I will review. Can't we still have a problem with local minima? Perhaps klgr's method to get close and then yours?

Comment: No it's global - from the documentation: *NArgMin always attempts to find a global minimum of f subject to the constraints given. *

Comment: I am looking at your method which does seem to be promising. On a technical point `NArgMin` will only find a global minimum if the function is linear. Our functions are not linear so we can have a problem with local minima.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to express the curve as a union of `ParametricRegions` and then use `RegionNearest`.

```
p1 = (List @@ Expand[(x + y)^3] /. {x -> 1 - t, y -> t}).pts[[1 ;; 4]];

p2 = (List @@ Expand[(x + y)^3] /. {x -> 1 - t, y -> t}).pts[[4 ;; 7]];

breg = RegionUnion[
  ParametricRegion[p1, {{t, 0, 1}}], 
  ParametricRegion[p2, {{t, 0, 1}}]
];

Region[Style[breg, Thick]]
```

[image]

```
RegionNearest[breg, pt]
```

> ```
> {0.0808892, 0.67102}
> ```

Comment: This is very elegant. Thank you I will look into it more. I have edited my question to show where I have got to.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
{min, pos} = FindMinimum[f1[t], {t, 0.99}, Method -> "Newton"]
minpt = {t, f1[t]} /. pos
Plot[f1[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {Orange, PointSize[0.03], Point[minpt]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think your point is even on the curve - could you check that?

Comment: @flinty Yes, I checked

Comment: @flinty please make sure you maintain  proper decency with people willing to help. It’s not what you think, you could have just asked Yarchik how you don’t understand the solution or at least said how the point seems to lie outside.

Comment: It *is* the wrong solution when you draw the curves `f1` and the `BezierCurve` - see my answer. Apologies for not explaining better but I only requested a check - I could have just downvoted and moved on.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I think the difficulty of multiple minima makes the `FindMimum` approach difficult. I have edited my question to show where I have got to.